# Creating check boxes dynamically inside the listview based on the layers loaded in QGIS

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a two list views named "Datacheckerlistview1" and "Datacheckerlistview2" in my gui. Now i had loaded layers in QGIS. Based on the number of layers loaded, i want check boxes to be created dynamically with the layer name inside the "Datacheckerlistview1"..( for ex: if there are 4 layers loaded, i want 4 check boxes to be created dynamically inside the Datacheckerlistview1). I had also attached my code below, i don't find any check boxes inside the list view with the code below. I am new to Python as well as QGIS. Help would be appreciated.

```
import os

from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
os.path.dirname(__file__), 'DataCheckerModule_dialog_base.ui'))


class DataCheckerClassDialog(QtGui.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
    """Constructor."""
    super(DataCheckerClassDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    # Set up the user interface from Designer.
    # After setupUI you can access any designer object by doing
    # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
    # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
    # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
    self.setupUi(self)

def dynamicCheckBoxes(self):
    """ Adds Checkboxes inside the listview dynamically based on the number of layers loaded in QGIS. """

    canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
    allLayers = canvas.layers()
    model = QStandardItemModel()
    for i in allLayers:
        item = QStandardItem('Item %s' % allLayers.name())
        check = Qt.checked if randint(0,1) == 1 else Qt.Unchecked
        item.setCheckState(check)
        item.setCheckable(True)
        model.appendRow(item)
        return model


    DatacheckerlistView1.setModel(model)
    DatacheckerlistView1.show()
```

And in the main Python file,

```
class DataCheckerClass:
  QObject.connect(self.dlg.DatacheckerlistView1, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.addLayers)

 def addLayers(self):
  super(DataCheckerClassDialog, self).dynamicCheckBoxes(self)
```

Comment: You create a `model` and add the checkboxes... but WHERE you attach the model to the view?

Comment: @ngulam: My edited code was the one which i tried recently.And also in the main python file, i made an action like when this DatacheckerlistView1 is clicked, then it should call the method something named  "addLayers"(in main Python file)  which is the inheritance of dynamicCheckBoxes method from DataCheckerClassDialog (our base class of ui). As a result nothing happened when i clicked the list view after the layers had been added in QGIS. Am i missing anything?

Comment: You have to show a (minimal) code example, we can't guess where the error is.
Up to now, we don't know where and how you bind action to the checkboxes.

Comment: The "return model" inside your for-loop causes the function to exit so the DatacheckerlistView1.show() will not be executed if there is a layer. If you remove the return statement you will get another error since the DatacheckerlistView1 is not defined in your dynamicCheckBoxes function.

Comment: Furthermore, should dynamicCheckBoxes be a member of the DataCheckerClassDialog? In that case you should indent it with the same number of spaces as the __init__ constructor (please use 4 space everywhere, not 1 or 2). If dynamicCheckBoxes is a stand-alone function, then remove the confusing `self` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes in the main python file and that works. Thanks for the efforts.

```
def addLayers(self):
    """ Adds Checkboxes inside the listview dynamically based on the number of layers loaded in QGIS. """

    canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
    allLayers = canvas.layers()
    if canvas.layerCount > 0:
        model = QStandardItemModel()
        for i in allLayers:
            item = QStandardItem('%s' % i.name())
            item.setCheckable(True)
            model.appendRow(item)



        self.dlg.DatacheckerlistView1.setModel(model)
        self.dlg.DatacheckerlistView1.show()
```